# The procedure entry point SystemParametersInfoForDpi could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt6Gui.dll

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

I recently installed open source (LGPL) Qt 6.4.1 from the online installer. After the installation, I tried to open Qt Creator from the start menu, but it gives this error:

> ##### qtcreator.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point SystemParametersInforForDpi not be located in the dynamic link library
> F:\apps\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Qt6Gui.dll.

I tried reinstalling but gives the same error.

How do I fix this?

I'm on Windows 8.1

Comment: `I'm on Windows 8.1` - see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/supported-platforms.html#windows - Windows 8.1 is no supported by Qt6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt 6 doesn't support Windows 8.1. That was the problem.

Source: [Qt Documentation — Supported Platforms](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/supported-platforms.html#windows).